# best practice to store authentication token in php application

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, redis

I am trying to work out what is the best and most efficient way of storing authentication token to get instant access next time I make a request.

Usually my initial request to obtain authentication token takes longer (1.5 seconds). Which means I can save a lot of time if I do that only once. All requests are done via CURL library (in my case its Guzzle but that does not matter).

My application is written in PHP and my options are

- Storing token using Redis and access it quickly - it should be quick as it Redis works "in memory"
- MySql - it is installed already and I may just need to create additional table
- Any other ideas?

Of course whenever I store authentication I am going to encode it and request for a new token once a day (not sure whats current ttl for the token but it doesnt matter).

I do care about access time (the quicker "read" the better)

Comment: How long do you intend to store the token?

Comment: There's quite a bit of information missing from your question.  What is the purpose of this authentication token?  How is it obtained?  What is the cause of the delay during the initial request?  What is your threat model?

Comment: probably I will store token for one day. I will update question with a bit more information but I think it has most key points

Comment: eggyal: All information is there, purpose of authentication token is to get data back based on credentials which its happening. It is obtained via curl library which is happening. The question is how you store that sensitive information so you can reuse token for my next request.

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike use encryption & decryption to store the access token in the database.